# Automatically rotate through image files?

Tags: graphics, loops

Note:  this is NOT about rotating the image *itself*.

In my book I have a bunch of decorative vignettes like this:

[image: first image]
,

[image]
,

and so on....

And I created a command for it:

`\newcommand*\vignette{\begin{center}
\includegraphics{vignette1.jpg}
\end{center}}`

But I want to automatically rotate through the images:

- vignette1.jpg
- vignette2.jpg
- vignette3.jpg
- .... etc

So that every time I invoke the command, it would include image #1, then #2, then #3, ... etc. and finally loop back to image #1 again.

How can I do that?

Comment: Would you give the angle value or it should be rotated by itself? If so please explain.

Comment: You can use `\newcommand*\vignette[1][0]{\begingroup\centering
\includegraphics[angle=#1]{vignette1.jpg}\endgroup}` and then `\vignette[30]`

Comment: No, I mean, every time I invoke the command, it would change the file number, eg: vignette1.jpg --> vignette2.jpg --> .... etc.

Comment: Question edited, sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: It's not quite clear to me whether you want to repeat the whole cycle of vignettes a number of times, or have only one cycle, end end it with vignette 1?

Comment: It should cycle through the list of files indefinitely.  Say, when it reaches #10 it goes back to #1 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Instead of `5` put the max number of files you have. The optional argument allow you to input a particular file if you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcount\sk@vignette
\newcommand*\vignette[1][]{\begingroup
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
    \global\advance\sk@vignette by\@ne\relax
\else
    \sk@vignette=#1\relax
\fi
\ifnum\sk@vignette>5\relax
\sk@vignette=\@ne\relax
\fi
\centering \includegraphics{vignette\the\sk@vignette.jpg}\par\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\vignette
\vignette
\vignette
\vignette
\vignette
\vignette
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the centering doesn't work and I changed it to `\begin{center} \includegraphics... \end{center}` and that has to be all in the same line.

Comment: You are right. The paragraph ends after group is closed, so the parameters set by `\centering` return to their original values. If you want center align, you need a `\par` before closing group. Using `center` environment put some vertical space before and after the image.

Answer (score 0):

An expl3 solution.

Optional parameter for specific file, without affecting the item counter; plus, a location macro (`\mypath`) which can point to vignettes (`./vignettes/vignette`) or elsewhere (e.g., in a group: `{\renewcommand\mypath{}\vignette[example-image-b]}` will scan texmf tree, then original definition of `\mypath` becomes visible again once the group is exited).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mypath{./vignettes/vignette}%folder/filename-prefix
\usepackage{graphicx}
%---------------------
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

    \int_new:N 
                    \g_vignette_int
                    
    \int_new:N 
                    \g_vignettemax_int
                

%---
\NewDocumentCommand { \setvignettemax } { m } {
    \int_gset:Nn
                    \g_vignettemax_int
                    { #1 }
}


%---
\NewDocumentCommand { \getvignette } { m } {

        \tl_set:Nn \l_myparm_tl { #1 }
        \par
        \centering
        \fbox{
                    \includegraphics[height=4em]{
                                    \mypath \tl_use:N \l_myparm_tl
                                                                                                        }
                }
                \par

}

\tl_new:N \l_myparm_tl

%---
\NewDocumentCommand { \vignette } { O{} } {

\tl_set:Nn \l_myparm_tl { #1 }

\tl_if_eq:NNTF 
     \c_empty_tl
             \l_myparm_tl 

            { % next item (in \mypath location)
                    \int_gincr:N
                                    \g_vignette_int
                    \int_compare:nNnTF
                                    { \g_vignette_int } > { \g_vignettemax_int }
                                    { \int_gset:Nn \g_vignette_int {1} }
                                    {  }
                    \getvignette { \int_use:N \g_vignette_int }
            } % end true
            { % specific item in \mypath location 
                 % (\mypath can be reset beforehand with \renewcommand)
                    \getvignette { #1 }
            }% end false
}


\ExplSyntaxOff
%---------------------



%-----
\begin{document}

\setvignettemax{3}

\vignette
\vignette
\vignette[2a]
\vignette[1]
\vignette


{\renewcommand\mypath{}\vignette[example-image-b]}
\vignette

\end{document}
```